# JQuery - :visible is not working

Tags: jquery, visible

I have a div with an id, whose preferences are stored in a .css file. The div is hidden in the beginning (`display:none`) and when the user types something into a form I show the div with `$(elem).hide().fadeIn();` and everything works okay.

I just want to check, in case the ESC key is used, whether the div is visible or not. I tried it with `if($(elem).is(':visible')` and `$('#suchergebnis').css('display') == 'block'`.

I echoed the display property and it always shows 'none' even when the div is visible.

How can this be and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I imagine that your `if` is been evaluated at a different time, under different conditiona, than you expect.

Comment: Have you tried $('#suchergebnis').is(':visible')  ..?

Comment: I've all JQuery-Code in `$(document).ready(function(){` and the `is(':visible')` in this code: `$(document).ready(function(){ $(document).keyup(function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 27) { //esc` ...

Comment: I just figured out, that i have to copy the code to another place. now it's detecting the visible box. However its not working properly.I want to do the following: If the user presses ESC and #suchergebnis is visible, this div should be hided. If he presses ESC and #suchergebnis is not visible the parent-div should be hided. I tried it with this code `if ($('#suchergebnis').is(':visible')) {
   $('#suchergebnis').hide();
  } else {
   $('#pop_layerbox').hide();
  }'If i have no `else` the first thing is working fine, but with the else i have both divs disappearing with only one press on esc...

Comment: Please update your question rather than adding extra details and code in comments. Show the if statement in the context of your keyup handler. And I second what Felix said: consider providing a (simplified) demo on http://jsfiddle.net